# iOS tab bar side scrolling is broken

Tags: ios, scroll, tableview, tabbar

I have a tableview which is in a tab bar controller (basically on of the tabs is a list of charts), vertical scrolling isn't responsive..sometimes it side scrolls to another tab if user accidentally moves finger a big to the side while scrolling vertically. That part is more optimized in other apps I've seen. Is there a way to make vertical scrolling smoother? Or just to disable the side scrolling in tab bar so user has to click the tabs to switch them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disable the side scrolling if you don't mind. it works for me. Thanks.

Comment: how can I disable it?

Comment: self.moreNavigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;   you can insert it in loadView or viewDidLoad of TabViewController.